# Drupal 7 doesn't show date field in block but it does in page

Tags: 7, blocks, datetime

I have a content type with a datetime iso field and pop-up calendar widget.
The field collects an end date too. 
In the view (page) and table format it shows correctly.

In the block in unformatted list it shows nothing as date (confirmed by having a label show up like Date:

If I make a new block with a table format then it shows.

So unformatted list can't show date fields with an end date? looks like a bug

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: When you click on the date field listed in the block display, for the settings do you see: "Formatter" with "Date and Time" selected. For "Display" is "Both start and end times" selected. Also make sure the "Exclude from display box" is not checked.

Comment: Yes these conditions are true and it is not excluded.

Comment: What is going on in the page source? Does any of the data show up in the source while not showing up on the page?

Comment: I am sorry but how can I view the page source? I am in a controlled environment and I just use the administration gui menus for making views/blocks.

Comment: The page source is the html that your browser is reading. It's what comes at the end of everything happening on the server; it's what gets sent to your browser.

In Firefox it's Tools => Web Developer => Page Source. In Chrome it is at: Tools => View Source.

Comment: oh haha. Sorry I didn't realize :) I thought it was a drupal view source thing. 

<div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="http://www.ati.ac.at/index.php?id=kontakte&amp;L=1%20%3D%3D%20Content%3A%20Link">Radiation Protection and Nuclear Engineering</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-training-date">        <div class="field-content"></div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-country">        <div class="field-content">AUSTRIA</div>  </div>  </div>

I am pretty sure it's a bug.

Comment: Can you export the view and post it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com). I would take a look at it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/S95SeYbv

Comment: On one of my sites I just created a View using the unformatted style settings in a block with a date field and a title field. It works fine. 

[Here is that export in a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TAe9c5qv). 

A quick comparison of my export with yours reveals that the section where the field definition for the date field ends, on mine, is: $handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['delta_offset'] = '0'; On yours it's: $handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_training_date']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;

Comment: I don't know enough about the internals of Views to absolutely know if this is the prolbem. I do know that mine works. I'd suggest creating a new view with just the block definition. Views ability to create multiple displays in a single views definition is great. But when I'm having problems, I'll often take the display I'm having trouble with and create it in a new View.